# Count, Group By, Subquery, Left Join not working as expected

Tags: mysql

This is puzzling me and no amount of the Google is helping me, hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Please note that I have omitted some fields from the tables that don't relate to the question just to simplify things.

**contacts**

```
contact_id
name
email
```

**contact_uuids**

```
uuid
contact_id
```

**visitor_activity**

```
uuid
event
```

**contact_communications**

```
comm_id
contact_id
employee_id
```

**Query**

```
SELECT 
  `c`.*,
  (SELECT COUNT(`log_id`) FROM `contact_communications` `cc`        WHERE `cc`.`contact_id` = `c`.`contact_id`) as `num_comms`,
  (SELECT MAX(`date`)   FROM `contact_communications` `cc`      WHERE `cc`.`contact_id` = `c`.`contact_id`) as `latest_date`,
  (SELECT MIN(`date`)   FROM `contact_communications` `cc`      WHERE `cc`.`contact_id` = `c`.`contact_id`) as `first_date`,
  (SELECT COUNT(`vaid`)     FROM `visitor_activity` `va`            WHERE `va`.`uuid`       = `cu`.`uuid`)      as `num_act`
FROM `contacts` `c`
LEFT JOIN `contact_uuids` `cu` ON `c`.`contact_id` = `cu`.`contact_id`
GROUP BY `c`.`contact_id`
ORDER BY `c`.`name` ASC
```

Some contacts have multiple UUIDs (upwards of 20 or 30).

When I perform the query WITHOUT the GROUP BY statement, I get the results I expect - a row returned for each UUID that exists for that contact, with the correct "num_comms" and "num_act" numbers.

However when I add the GROUP BY statement, the "num_comms" is a lot smaller then expected and the "num_act" returns only the value from the first row without the GROUP BY statement.

I tried doing a "WHERE NOT IN" in the subquery, however that simply crashed the server as it was far too intense.

So - how do I get this to add up all the COUNT values from the LEFT JOIN and not just return the first value?

Also if anyone can help me optimize this that would be great.

Comment: `SELECT `c`.,` – is that even valid syntax? Also, it might help if you could provide example data and the desired output, preferably in an easily testable format like an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: maybe he missed the `*`  and ment to say `SELECT c.*`

Comment: Please find the "edit" button.

Comment: Ack - you guys are absolutely correct.  My apologies.  I was in the middle of testing different queries when I copy/pasted that and must have done it right in the middle of a change.  Will edit now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

- GROUP BY `c`.`contact_id` does not include all the non-aggregate columns.  This is a MySQL extension.  What you get is random values for the rows other than contact_id
- The JOIN adds confusion.  Your only use for visitor_activity is the COUNT(*) one it.  But that does not make sense since it is limited to one UUID, whereas the row is limited to one contact_id.  Rethink the purpose of that.

Remove this line:

```
  (SELECT COUNT(`vaid`) FROM `visitor_activity` `va` WHERE `va`.`uuid`       = `cu`.`uuid`) as `num_act`
```

and the rest may work ok.

I will continue with the assumption that you want the COUNT of all rows in visitor_activity for all the uuids associated with the one contact_id.

See if this:

```
( SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM  `contacts` c2
    JOIN  `visitor_activity` USING(uuid)
    WHERE  c2.contact_id = c.contact_id as `num_act` ) AS  num_act
```

will work for the last subquery.  At the same time, remove the JOIN:

```
LEFT JOIN `contact_uuids` `cu` ON `c`.`contact_id` = `cu`.`contact_id`
```

Now, back to the other problem (the non-standard usage of GROUP BY).  Assuming that contact_id is the PRIMARY KEY, then simply remove the

```
GROUP BY `c`.`contact_id`
```

Comment: Thanks for all the great info. Your last subquery does not work though because uuid does not exist in the contact table, it exists in the contact_uuids table which is why I thought I had to join them like I did. Any contact can have any number of uuids.

Comment: On further thought it appears I could use the contact_uuids as the from in your subquery.  Will try and report back.

Comment: Yea that was it - just needed to change "from `contacts` c2" to "from `contact_uuids` ...."  Excellent.  Thanks so much.